# Why does GCC 4.2.1 ignore #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-qual" under certain conditions?

Tags: gcc, pragma

Here is my test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wcast-qual"

static void proc(char *buf)
{
    printf("buf=%p\n",buf);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    const char *cbuf;
    char *buf = (char *)cbuf;
    proc(buf);
    return(0);
}
```

Here is my compile:

```
$ g++ -Wcast-qual    x.cpp
x.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
x.cpp:13: warning: cast from type ‘const char*’ to type ‘char*’ casts away constness
$
```

And here is the compile without the -Wcast-qual:

```
$ g++ x.cpp
$
```

I've used `#pragma GCC diagnostic ignored` in other places of my code without problems. Here it is not working. Can somebody tell me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a compiler bug on the Mac. GCC 4.7.2 on Linux does not have this problem.  Neither does clang++. On the Mac you should try to use clang++, not g++.

Apple should update its compiler.